# Strange set notation (a set as a power of 2)?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am not very well versed on set theory or syntax, but I thought I knew the basics.

However, in a book about databases I am reading now, the author uses $2^x$ to signify "a set of $x$."

For example, $2^{\text{dogs}}$ is a set of $\text {dogs}$, etc.

The author never really explained this or why he does it, I just picked up the meaning from context.

I am not sure why the exponent operator is used, nor am I sure what the number $2$ has to do with it.  The sets being represented are NOT powers of $2$ (in size)... they come in all sizes.

Is this a valid notation?  I have not seen it anywhere before...

Comment: `2^dogs` is more likely to mean the set of all possible sets with dogs as elements (including the empty set and the set of all dogs)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The notation $2^S$ denotes the [*power set*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of S, i.e. the set of all subsets of S, also denoted $\mathcal P(S)$.

- The notation is in fact well chosen, with regard to the notation $X^Y$ to denote the set of all functions $Y\to X$: if we let $X = 2 = \{0,1\}$, then a function $f:Y\to \{0,1\}$ corresponds uniquely to a subset $S \subseteq Y$ if we let $x\in S\iff f(x)=1$.
- As a special case, when $S$ is finite the order of $\mathcal P(S)$ is in fact $|\mathcal P(S)| = 2^{|S|}$, a fact useful to remember what the notation means. (This generalizes to $|X|^{|Y|} = |X^Y|$ for arbitrary sets.)
- The notation $\binom{S}{i}$ is also being used: it is the set of all subsets of $S$ that contain exactly $i$ elements. Here too, $\binom{|S|}{i} = \left|\binom{S}{i}\right|$.

Comment: $2 = \{0,1\}$ is a reference to [von Neumann ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers#Definition_as_von_Neumann_ordinals), for anyone else who has no idea what that means.

Answer (score 9):

If $X$ is a finite set, say, it has $n$ elements, then the power set of $X$ is the collection of all subsets of $X$ which has exactly $2^n$ numbers of elements. That's why people use $2^X$ to denote the power set of $X$.

For example, $X=\{1,2,3\}$, then the power set of $X$ is given by 
$$2^X=\Big\{\emptyset,\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\},X=\{1,2,3\}\Big\},$$
which has $2^3=8$ elements.

However, for infinite set $X$, of course the power set of $X$, $2^X$ is also infinite.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this notation and found an explanation in a book on set theory. Actually, 2^n is not a power set, but a set with a one-to-one correspondence with it:
[from SET THEORY CHARLES C. PINTER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKMkm.png)

P.s. 2 is a set of two elements {0,1}

Answer (score 0):

This notation was also used in Chandra and Toueg's seminal paper [Unreliable Failure Detectors in Reliable Systems](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/226643.226647) on page 231, par. 2.1. It was used to denote a powerset.

The notation 2<sup>S</sup>, given that 2 ∈ ℕ<sup>0</sup> and S is a finite set, appears to be mathematically aburd at first glance. The literal 2 here, by the way, is the von Neumann ordinal 2 = {0, 1}. Notice that |2<sup>S</sup>| = 2<sup>|S|</sup> = |2|<sup>|S|</sup>, which aligns with cardinal arithmetic and is very convenient indeed.

Comment: More than a decade later. Does this answer add anything to the ones already given?