# What does 2 to the power x mean in set theory

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, notation, matching-theory

In a mathematics assignments i encounter the following statement:

We have a finite collection of combinatorial objects $S \subseteq 2^x$ (For example matchings or spanning trees)

What does this notation $S \subseteq 2^x$ mean (Especially the $2^x$ part)?

Comment: It's the power set

Comment: See [Power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set): "the power set of any set $X$ is the set of all subsets of $X$, including the empty set and $X$ itself, variously denoted as $\mathcal P(X), ℘(S)$, or, identifying the powerset of $X$ with the set of all functions from $X$ to a given set of two elements, $2^X$. Any subset of $\mathcal P(X)$ is called a *family of sets* over $X$."

Comment: Thus, $S⊆2^X$  means that $S$ is a *family of sets* over $X$, i.e. a set of *subsets* of $X$.

Comment: The following question answers it better.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104522/strange-set-notation-a-set-as-a-power-of-2

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are sets then $A^B$ is the collection of functions from $B$ to $A$. When you see the notation $2^X$, where $X$ is a set, we're also considering $2$ as a set, in fact $$2=\{0,1\}.$$ So $2^X$ is the collection of all functions mapping $X$ to $\{0,1\}$.

It's been stated in a comment that $2^X$ is the power set of $X$, that is, the collection of all subsets of $X$. That's not literally true, but there's an obvious and standard one-to-one correspondence between $2^X$ and the power set of $X$, given by $f\mapsto\{x:f(x)=1\}$.

Comment: "obvious and standard".  And a big stumbling block for most students the first few times they see it.  Might not be remiss to actually spell it out... or not.

Comment: I didn't know that $A^B = \{f \mid f:B \to A\}$! Where does one learn this? Until I read this post, I thought that $2^{\Omega}$ meant the power set of a sample space because people thought that $|2^{\Omega}| = 2^{|\Omega|}$ was "clean notation"!

Comment: @Clarinetist, what you call "clean notation" is how powers of natural numbers are _defined_ (or more precisely, cardinal numbers). It is set theory where you learn it.

Comment: @Clarinetist You should take it as an exercise to figure out how $A^2$, by this definition, is naturally equivalent to $A\times A$. Similarly for $A^3$, after you figure out what set $3$ should be...

Comment: Woah, retweet (If this were Twitter.. ☺) @Clarinetist! The notation is a lot more judicious than I realized!