# Defining a tricky function: $(A \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(B)) \rightarrow\mathcal{P}(A \rightarrow B)$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

How would I define a function of the form:

\begin{align*}
\phi: (A \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(B)) \rightarrow\mathcal{P}(A \rightarrow B)
\end{align*}

I know what behaviour I want, I'm just struggling to define it. For example,
consider a function 
\begin{align*}
&f: {0, 1} \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(\{0, 1, 2, 3\}) \\
&f(0) = \{0, 1\} \\
&f(1) = \{2, 3\} \\
\end{align*}

I want $\phi(f)$ to be:
\begin{align*}
&\phi(f) = \{g_1, g_2, g_3, g_4 \} \\
&g_1(0) = 0 \qquad g_1(1) = 2 \\
&g_2(0) = 0 \qquad g_2(1) = 3 \\
&g_3(0) = 1 \qquad g_3(1) = 2 \\
&g_4(0) = 1 \qquad g_4(2) = 3 \\
\end{align*}

That is, I want all possible combinations of $\{0, 1\} \times \{2, 3\}$ *as functions*.

Comment: It seems to me that you are asking about [*Cartesian product*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#Infinite_Cartesian_products): if $(X_a)_{a\in A}$ is a family of sets indexed by $A$, then $$ \prod_{a \in A} X_a = \left\{ g : A \to \bigcup_{a \in A} X_a \, \middle| \, g(a) \in X_a \text{ for all } a \in A \right\}. $$ In such case, $\phi(f) = \prod_{a \in A} f(a)$.

Comment: Is there anyway you could rewrite this so that you aren't reusing the symbols $0$ and $1$?  It just makes trying to figure out what you are asking for harder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elements of $\phi(f)$ are exactly those $g \colon A \to B$ for which
$$\forall a \in A: g(a) \in f(a).$$
They are *choice functions*: for every $a \in A$, they *choose* an element $g(a) \in f(a)$. The fact such a function, in general, exists at all is the axiom of choice.

Comment: The generality of invoking choice is only necessary for infinite products, which is not the case here. Is there some slick way to define the family of choice functions?

Comment: It's not clear from your question that you want $A$ and $B$ to be finite. Anyway, that doesn't matter for the _definition_ of $\phi(f)$. It still is $\{ g \colon A \to B \;|\; \forall a \in A: g(a) \in f(a)\}$. For finite $A$ and $B$, that set contains $\prod_{a \in A} |f(a)|$ elements. You only need choice to prove that (in the general case, not restricting to finite $A$ and $B$), the set is non-empty (assuming $f(a)$ is never empty, of course).

Answer (score 1):

This is not properly speaking an answer to the question ; it is an attempt to see more clearly what all this is about.

I will use the term "application" as a synonym to a function $f:E \to F$ such that *every* $e \in E$ has an image $f(e) \in F$.

You must know the following notations :

- $F^{E}$ for the set of applications from $E$ to $F$ and, as a particular case
- $\{0,1\}^G \cong 2^G$ for the (well named) power set, i.e., the set of subsets of set $G$.

(see for example : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/104524)

If I understand well, you are asking whether there is a (more or less natural) way to find a "path" between :

$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ S_1:=(2^B)^{A}\cong 2^{B \times A}$ and $S_2=2^{(B^{A})}.$

The first isomorphism drives us to the partitions of the cartesian product $B \times A$ or the isomorphic set $A \times B$. Among such partitions, there are those which define an application from $A$ to $B$, i.e., a partition that is $\{(a_1,b_1),(a_2,b_2),...(a_n,b_n)\}$ where $\{a_1,a_2,...a_n\}=A$ (every element of set $A$ is present exactly once). Thus, in a certain sense, the set of applications $f:A \to B$ is included into $S_1$.

Concerning $S_2=2^{(B^{A})}$, it could be described as the ways to group applications. It is a much "larger" set than $S_1$, and I don't see any clearcut correspondence between  $S_1$ and $S_2$.